# Import or restore MySQL databases from var directory

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mysql

I recently backed up my entire laptop hard drive with SuperDuper and reinstalled Snow Leopard. Because I made an image clone, I was able to restore all my files without losing any data. Go hard drive cloning.

However, the one thing I forgot to do was to do a dump of all my MySQL databases. Eek. Because of the nature of MySQL's storage, I can't just drag and drop the databases and tables—all the data is locked up in the server.

When I mount the cloned image I can navigate to `/Volumes/laptop/usr/local/mysql/var` (since I had installed MySQL to `/usr/local/mysql`) and I can see all my databases listed as directories with random files inside, which seems promising.

What should I do to restore all those databases I forgot to dump? Is there a way to restore the `var/` folder to my new, fresh installation of MySQL and (hopefully) maintain all the users and privileges? Can I just copy that directory and have everything work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Disclaimer:*** I can't guarantee that this works for you too, it did for me.

I've done similar restorations (under Windows, though) by simply copying the files (the whole `/usr/local/mysql` directory...shouldn't that be under `/var/mysql` anyway?). Of course you'll need to stop the MySQL daemon and restart if after you're done.

Also, check the file permissions, just in case that something has changed.

Comment: Excellent. A variation of your idea worked. All the MySQL data was in `/usr/local/mysql/var`, so I copied the original folder over to my new installation (not the whole `/usr/local/mysql` directory… just the `var`) and I made sure the mysql user could access it (`sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/mysql/var`). The trickiest part was telling MySQL to look at it. Once I ran the install_db script (`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_install_db --user=_mysql`), everything worked perfectly. Amazing!