# Restore SQL Database from full system backup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, mysqldump

long story short I am restoring a failed server. I have a backup of most of the file system. I need to restore the SQL databases but I don't have a copy of the mysqldump. so I've restored the files to /var/lib/mysql. But when I try to view the tables the database is empty.

Can this be done? And what other steps do I need to take? at the very least can I mount this DB somewhere where I can read the data and recreate the pages and articles?

Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: can this be done and how?  ill put it in an edit.

Comment: The transfered tables are an empty set. I only moved the folders with the names of the tables. should I move the whole mysql folder?

Comment: The whole `/var/lib/mysql` folder, yes. I thought you had done that since you've stated it in your question.

Comment: so now im getting this error when starting mysql.

`mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-01-10 19:39:00 UTC; 15s ago

  Process: 3089 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  
Process: 3067 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`
im sorry the formating looks horrible here.

Comment: Please just edit the question to include any additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @slhck!

The solution was not to copy the entire mysql folder but just the folder of the databases you need (in my case `DerekFrelow_com`) the thing I forgot to do was change my permissions on the folder.

I noticed the more comments we had the more relevant the "related Links got" so here is the source that gave me the ah-ha moment.

[Import or restore MySQL databases from var directory](https://superuser.com/questions/165575/import-or-restore-mysql-databases-from-var-directory?rq=1)